# Change the child item innertext in a webtable in uft?

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, qtp, browser-automation, uft14

Please help me in changing the `innertext` of a `WebElement` from a `Webtable`. Below is the code which I am trying

```
SET OBJECT = Browser("Browser").Page("pgeMemberProgram").WebTable("Member Summary").ChildItem(18, 2, "WebElement", 9)

OBJECT.set "ABCD"
```

Every time I am trying this it says, OBJECT is not set.

Answer (score 0):

`WebElement` objects don't have a `Set` method. In order to set their text you have to use the [`.Object` property](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Common_Methods_and_Properties/Common_Methods_and_Properties.html#Object) in order to access the underlying HTML object.

Note that `innerText` is not standard HTML, you should use `textContent`. Most browsers support `textContent` but if you're using older versions of IE you may need to use `innerText`.

You may be also facing problems due to use of `OBJECT` as the variable name, try the following:

```
Set webElem = Browser("Browser").Page("pgeMemberProgram").WebTable("Member Summary").ChildItem(18, 2, "WebElement", 9)

webElem.Object.textContent = "ABCD"
```